# Swap index values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a (two-level) multi-index and would like to swap levels **only if** a condition is met. In my case, the condition is if the second index is lexicographically lower than the first.
I know there is the [`swaplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html?highlight=swaplevels) method, but it doesn't allow conditional swaps.

```py
>>> data = [["b", "a", 10], ["g", "t", 1], ["s", "c", 5]]
>>> cols = ["idx1", "idx2", "val"]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols).set_index(cols[:2])

           val
idx1 idx2     
b    a      10
g    t       1
s    c       5
```

and I would like to change it to

```
           val
idx1 idx2     
a    b      10
g    t       1
c    s       5
```

Comment: Possibly rebuild the index: ``df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([sorted(ent) for ent in df.index], names=df.index.names)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rebuild the index:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([sorted(ent) for ent in df.index],
                                      names=df.index.names)
```